# Turn pseudocode into functioning code to find greatest common divisor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the pseudocode here that says: Initialize d to the smaller of m and n.
While d does not evenly divide m or d does not evenly divide n do
Decrease the value of d by 1
Report d as the greatest common divisor of n and m

and I can't figure out what's preventing my code from working. I'll post my code below, if you could take a look for me and tell me what's preventing my code from working properly I'd appreciate it.

```
m = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
n = int(input("Enter another positive integer: "))
d = min(m,n)
while True:
    if d % m != 0 or d % n != 0:
        d -= 1

    elif d % m == 0 and d % n == 0:
        print(d)
        break
```

Comment: I think you have your `%` operands the wrong way round. If d is a divisor of n then `n % d == 0`

Comment: Read the pseudocode, read your code and you'll find the problem. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find if a value evenly divides another, you need to have the smaller (divisor) on the right side of the modulus operator. So change your code to:

```py
if (m %d != 0) or (n % d != 0):
```

This evaluates if `d` evenly divides `m`or `n`, instead of if `m` or `n` evenly divide `d`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your `if` is basically the opposite of your `elif` condition, and to evenly divide `m` means `m` should be the left side of the modulo operator (same thing for `n`). I made an edit here to show what I mean:

```
m = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
n = int(input("Enter another positive integer: "))
d = min(m,n)
while m % d != 0 or n % d != 0:
    d -= 1
print(d)
```